# Selecting one row from duplicated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a loooooong stored procedure that runs about 15 select statements across different tables in a database - I am inserting all the results of the selects into a temporary table.  However - that table has some rows that are exact duplicates.  The temporary table looks something like this:

```
DocID   | VisitDate            | DocName
8245376 | 8/26/2009 1:07:01 PM | Doc1   
8245376 | 8/26/2009 1:07:01 PM | Doc1   
8245376 | 8/26/2009 1:07:01 PM | Doc2   
8245376 | 8/26/2009 1:07:01 PM | Doc2   
646681  | 8/26/2009 1:07:01 PM | Doc3    
263272  | 8/26/2009 1:07:01 PM | Doc4   
8245376 | 8/26/2009 1:07:01 PM | Doc5   
8245376 | 8/26/2009 1:07:01 PM | Doc5   
8245376 | 8/26/2009 1:07:01 PM | Doc6   
8245376 | 8/26/2009 1:07:01 PM | Doc6   
1903875 | 8/26/2009 1:07:01 PM | Doc7
```

And how I'd like the table to look at the end is like this:

```
DocID   | VisitDate            | DocName
8245376 | 8/26/2009 1:07:01 PM | Doc1   
8245376 | 8/26/2009 1:07:01 PM | Doc2   
646681  | 8/26/2009 1:07:01 PM | Doc3    
263272  | 8/26/2009 1:07:01 PM | Doc4   
8245376 | 8/26/2009 1:07:01 PM | Doc5   
8245376 | 8/26/2009 1:07:01 PM | Doc6   
1903875 | 8/26/2009 1:07:01 PM | Doc7
```

How can I return only ONE row if there are multiple duplicate rows and still return rows that are not duplicates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT DocID, VisitDate, DocName
FROM    mytable
```

Or I am missing something?

**Update:**

If you have control over the stored procedure, you can rewrite it so that no duplicates will ever get into the table.

Assuming `DocID` is a `PRIMARY KEY`, declare it as such in the temporary table using `IGNORE_DUP_KEY`:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (DocId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON), …)

INSERT
INTO    @mytable
SELECT  …
FROM    source_table
```

This will skip duplicates on `DocID`

Comment: INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)...@Quassnoi this line saved me from a blunder..

Answer (score 2):

Try `SELECT DISTINCT` instead of `SELECT`. `DISTINCT` keyword will remove the duplicate value

Answer (score 2):

If the duplicates are coming from the source tables, then do a SELECT DISTINCT when you are doing an insert into your temp tables.

If the duplicates are coming *across* tables, then just do a SELECT DISTINCT from your temp table after you have inserted all the rows.

Trying to actually *delete rows from a table that are duplicate* is a bit more involved, but doesn't seem to be necessary here, because you are working with a temp table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to eliminate the duplicates from the temp table or better yet, don't put them in there in the first place, turn you multiple selects into a larger union query and insert that result into your temp table.